# Do people that are called through FaceTime show up on my carrier's bill?

Tags: cellular-carriers

I was just wondering if FaceTime calls show up on my carrier's (Sprint) bill as a regular call, like the number that was FaceTimed and when and the length of the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Facetime uses [Wifi or Cellular](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204380) data so will **not** show as regular calls on your carrier bill.

> 1. You can use FaceTime on any of these devices on Wi-Fi: iPhone 4 or later, iPad Pro (all models), iPad 2 or later, iPad mini (all models), and iPod touch 4th generation or later (only iPod touch 5th generation or later support FaceTime audio calling).
> 2. With a cellular data plan, you can also use FaceTime without Wi-Fi on any of these devices: iPhone 4s or later, iPad Pro (all models), and iPad (3rd generation or later).

Details of your FaceTime call history are stored locally on your device.